# Can't fit my navbar links inside the navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm setting up a portfolio page for an assignment. I made some changes to my code, and now my navbar isn't working properly. I can't get my page links to fit in my actual navbar they are sitting below it for some reason.

I've tried messing with the padding and margins, but that's not doing anything. It was working fine at one point but I'm not sure what changed.

HTML:

```
<nav>
        <p>STEVEN KANG</p>
        <ul>
            <li class="rightLinks"><a data-scroll-target="contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="rightLinks"><a data-scroll-target="projects">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="rightLinks"><a data-scroll-target="bio">Bio</a></li>
         </ul>
        <div class="menu-toggle">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    background-color: black;
    height:60px;
    color: #666666;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width: 100%;
}

nav p {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
}

nav a {
    color: red;
}

nav ul {
    margin-bottom: 5em;
}

.rightLinks {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Those bio, portfolio, and contact links should be on the right centered inside the navbar mirroring my

element saying my name.

I feel like it's a simple fix, I'm just not sure what's wrong right now.

Comment: Hi Ginsole, could you provide an example via jsfiddle or codepen please?

Comment: Ok bear with me. First time using stack overflow and codepen. I created a super barebones version of my page, but it's showing the same problem so I think this will work. Here's the link. https://codepen.io/skang28/pen/dxOXYm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken a look at your code. It looks like you need to to utilise floats and a clearfix in order to achieve this.

Take a look at: https://codepen.io/mrmathewc/pen/OKbXRY

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Steven Kang - Developer</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="float-left">
        <p>STEVEN KANG</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="float-right">
            <li class="rightLinks"><a data-scroll-target="contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="rightLinks"><a data-scroll-target="projects">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="rightLinks"><a data-scroll-target="bio">Bio</a></li>
         </ul>
        <div class="menu-toggle">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
        </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </nav>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif; 
    font-size: 48px;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #0047b3;
    ;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav {
    background-color: black;
    height:60px;
    color: #666666;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width: 100%;
}

nav p {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
}

nav a {
    color: #0047b3;
}

nav ul {
    margin-bottom: 5em;
}

.rightLinks {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.float-left {
  float: left;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
}
.clearfix { clear: both; }
```

I would recommend looking into Flexbox though, floats can give you some headaches.

Here's a basic example: https://codepen.io/mrmathewc/pen/wVoWgV

You'll need to extend the above to your code. This may help you understand Flexbox more: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Appreciate the help. So it does look better but when I use display: flex, I can't move the links to the right of the navbar? align-content and text-align don't seem to be doing anything. What can I use?

Comment: So when you have two divs for example and the parent div which contains them both has `display: flex;` assigned, you want to just ass `justify-content: space-between;` on the parent which will push both elements away from each other as far as the container permits.

Comment: Ok that worked! I had to apply it in the parent not the actual ul. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it worked! :) As a side note, make sure to add other browser support to your code. Autoprefixer (https://autoprefixer.github.io/) should help you with that. Please mark my answer as correct if it worked for you :)